# How to perform this operation in a view with Query builder and pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a "teachers" table and a "courses" table. I get to access my "courses" data when I'm on a "teachers" view with a foreach.

```
@foreach($teacher->courses as $course)
    <li>{{ $course->title }}</li>
@endforeach
```

But I would like to hide the section if it "teachers" has no "course".

```
@if(teacher_has_course)
 <section class="My section">

   @foreach($teacher->courses as $course)
    <li>{{ $course->title }}</li>
   @endforeach

 </section>
@endif
```

I do not understand the principle. Can you help me ? Thank you

Comment: `@if($teacher->courses->count() > 0)` **OR** `@if(count($teacher->courses) > 0)`

Comment: *But I would like to hide the section if it "teachers" has no "course".* entire section on relevent `<li>` only show example as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check like this:

```
@if(!empty($teacher->courses) && count($teacher->courses))
 <section class="My section">

   @foreach($teacher->courses as $course)
    <li>{{ $course->title }}</li>
   @endforeach

 </section>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works, but I would like to understand why? If I do a var_dump of "$ teacher-> races" I have a lot of data, how does it know?

Comment: It's a relationship between model. for more info review [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)
and don't forget to mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="My section">
   @foreach($teacher->courses as $course)
       @unless(!$course)
        <li>{{ $course->title }}</li>
       @endunless
   @endforeach
</section>
```

or

```
@unless(!$teacher->courses)
    <section class="My section">
        @foreach($teacher->courses as $course)     
            <li>{{ $course->title }}</li>
        @endforeach
   </section>
@endunless
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined a relation between two tables you can use `->has()` method. Lets say there is one to many relation between 'teachers' and 'courses' then you can check like this

```
@if($teacher->has('course'))
    // html code that you want to show
@endif
```

Refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Hope this helps